# How to extract props and states from one sibling component to another with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem of passing props and states from one component to another.

the parent component renders as below

```
 const Countdown = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Timer taskNumber={1} />
      <ClickScore taskNumber={1} numberOfAnswers={3} />
      <FailScreen taskNumber={1}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Timer component as below:

```
  const Timer = () => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timer > 0) {
        setTimer((timer) => timer - 1);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        if (score < numberOfAnswers) {
          history.push("/timesup");
        }
        history.push(`/tasks/${taskNumber}/page/3`);
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timer, history]);

  return <div className="countdown">{timer}</div>;
};
```

ClickScore component as below:

```
  const ClickScore = ({ taskNumber, numberOfAnswers }) => {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  const onGridClick = (row, col) => {
    if (taskNumber === 1) {
      if (
        (row === 1 && col === 2) ||
        (row === 2 && col === 1) ||
        (row === 2 && col === 3)
      ) {
        setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1);
      }
      return `${score}/${numberOfAnswers}`;
    }
   };

  const GridCell = ({ style, onGridClick }) => {
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = () => {
      if (!clicked) {
        setClicked(true);
        onGridClick();
      }
    };
    return (
      <div
        style={{...style}}
        onClick={handleClick}
        disable={clicked}></div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <p id="score">{`${score}/${numberOfAnswers}`}</p>
      </div>
      <GridCell
        onGridClick={() => onGridClick(1, 1)}
        style={{
          left: 3,
          height: 170.48,
          width: 290.86,
          top: 37.91,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

FailScreen component:

```
 const FailScreen = ({ prompt, taskNumber }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <PromptBox
        title="Time's Up!"
        msg={`Oh no! You didn’t find all the ${prompt}`}
      />
      <Link to={`/tasks/${taskNumber}/page/1`}>
        <Button
          btn="tryAgainBtn
          name="TRY AGAIN"
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
 );
```

};

My problem is in Timer component, I need the state 'score' from ClickScore as well as its props ('taskNumber and numberOfAnswers}. I also need taskNumber for FailScreen component. I tried useContext hook but I still had hard time referencing the state 'score'. I thought useContext is for passing props among components. I'm also thinking about using ref fowarding, or useCallback or memo, but not sure I'm on the right track.

Comment: IMHO as you're intending to use `score`, `taskNumber` and `numberOfAnswers` in at least two components, a better choice would be through using context

Comment: How can I get the score state besides those props? That’s where I got stuck.

Comment: You first have to create a context with the score value and score setter. You then get values from this context in the components you want. I'll make an answer try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass props among components, they have to be available in their common parent. To make the score state value as a shared context value, you could then do :

```
const ScoreContext = useContext([]);

const ScoreProvider = (props) => {
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0); // Assuming your initial score is 0
    
    return (
        <ScoreContext.Provider value={[score, setScore]}>
            {props.children}
        </ScoreContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

You then wrap the child components in this Context provider like :

```
const Countdown = () => {
    return (
        <ScoreProvider>
            <div>
                <Timer taskNumber={1} />
                <ClickScore taskNumber={1} numberOfAnswers={3} />
                <FailScreen taskNumber={1}/>
            </div>
        </ScoreProvider>
);
```

};

In the `ClickScore` component, this line : `const [score, setScore] = useState(0);` should then become `const [score, setScore] = useContext(ScoreContext);` in order to use and update the score. In each of the remaining components, you just access the score value then with `const [score] = useContext(ScoreContext);`

Comment: Thanks for your sample code. So you set ScoreProvider's value just for score, is it true I need to also add taskNumber, numberOfAnswers and define them as ' let taskNumber, numberOfAnswers; '?

Comment: It depends. Are you going to update their values in other components??

Comment: Timer and ClickScore need all 3,  and FailScreen needs taskNumber.

Comment: Just for display, or will they update it? If it's just for display, you could then just pass them as prop as you're doing right now. You may initialize them (if you want) as variables in order to change them once. If you want to update their value, you could either include them in your context or use a global state object

Comment: I think the score need to be updated for every rendering and taskNumber and numberoOfAnswers need to display. So after I put value = {([score, setScore], taskNumber, numberOfAnswers)} it gave me this error 'TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))'

Comment: I thought I had to mention taskNumber and numberOfAnswers somehow in ScoreProvider otherwise other components won't know what they are.

Comment: IMHO  other components are already aware of `taskNumber` and `numberOfAnswers`  as you're passing them as props to them. A simple way of doing this may be to first initialize them like (if I suppose they won't change) : `const taskNumber = 1; const numberOfAnswers = 3;`. Then for each component you just pass them like : `numberOfAnswers={numberOfAnswers}` or `taskNumber={taskNumber}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227827/discussion-between-kraph-and-coderonpointe).

Comment: It worked this time when I just passed in the state instead of passing 3 props! Thanks again!

Comment: That's great. Glad to have helped you

Answer (score 0):

Without using `context API` or a state management tool (which would be best if you'd have a lot of this going on), you can just create some `useState` variables, then create a few functions which update those variables and pass the functions through to the `components`. The `components` can then use those functions and pass in the value they need to, then the function will run and update the state in the `parent component`.

It does get a bit messy like that so Context API would be better but here's an example:

**Countdown Component:**

```
const Countdown = () => {
// create state for the click score
const [clickScore, setClickScore] = useState(0)

// create a function that will update the click store with given value
const updateClickScore = (score) => {
  setClickScore(score)
}
  return (
    <div>
      // Let's pass the updateClickScore function to Timer
      <Timer taskNumber={1} clickscore={updateClickScore} />

      // You can also pass the clickScore as a prop so other components can access it
      <ClickScore taskNumber={1} numberOfAnswers={3} score={clickScore} />

      // lets do it so the Failscreen can access it too, providing it needs to:
      <FailScreen taskNumber={1} score={clickScore} />

      // Now whenever the update is made, all components will receive the value

    </div>
  );
};
```

**Timer Component:**

```
 const Timer = (clickscore) => {
   // your logic here

   // as an example lets pass the function to button click we will pass it the value 1 when clicked
   
// this will run the function in the Countdown component
    return <button onClick={() => clickscore(1)>Click Me</button>

   // Now once that has been clicked, all components will display 1 wherever the score prop is being rendered inside of them.
}
```

So the function you passed through as a `prop` from within `Countdown` to `Timer` can now by used by calling `clickscore(x)` in Timer. This will run the function that is in the `Countdown component` and pass your number through which will then be updated in the state in `Countdown`.

You can then pass the `clickScore` state that resides in `Countdown` to any of the `components` as a prop. So they will all access the same number, if that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanations and sample code. It totally makes sense. I definitely think my app is better off using useContext as there will be more like this coming up as I foresee it.

Comment: I was trying to implement your code but got confused about why you pass differently to Timer vs ClickScore component. One is a number, the other is a callback. Inside of ClickScore, since the state 'score' is lifted up, how do I use callback prop to implement this logic like setScore(prev=> prev + 1)?

Comment: So in timer I'm passing down the function to increase the score (which will update in the parent). This makes the score accessible to all of its siblings as they are within the parent. Now in the siblings I pass through the score so they can all access the value. Once the score is updated, the value will update in all of the components. You just need to run the setScore in the parent. So if it's a prev button, you create a prev function in the parent and add set score, then pass it down to the child that needs to trigger it on click. The state then stays in the parent,  the child triggers it